# Offline symfony2 application

Tags: javascript, symfony, offline

***Situation***

I'm building a little chat using Symfony2. I'm wondering if there are possibilities to make the chat usable in offline mode. I'm not expecting to actively chat with connected user. I'm planning to make the user able to write message in offline mode (in the metro for instance), and then send it when connection is back again. Important: I would like to compute in the fact that connection can be gone for a long time. I remember beeing with people working in the Eurostar (Paris - London) and using their computers/phone while in a submarine tunnel for an hour or so. There was no connection at all. So in this case, how can you store a message for such a long time before sending it?

***Problem***

I found some interesting tutorial defining the HTML 5 offline mode. They define the capabilities of this offline mode with sending message but doesn't give example. Moreover, it seems that the only stuff we can put in the manifest are static files (css, javascript, html, pictures...)

My question is then, how do you store the written message from the user after she/he pressed the "send" button and is offline? Is it a javascript variable? Or is there html 5 features that exist?

Cheers!

Comment: Essentially you need to have a Javascript application (with a backend that could be Symfony2) to work offline. Any code that runs on the server (e.g. Symfony code) needs an internet connection to work.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that's what I thought indeed!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do this via `HTML5 local storage`:

http://www.redrobotzoo.com/posts/html5-local-storage-and-local-databases-tutorial/

This example has very nice examples so it should not be a problem for you to make it work.

Comment: Thanks jperovic! That seems perfect. I'll try it and see what I can do with it.